# Usecases documentation and code

Tags: corda

Where can I find existing or on going developed usecase/smart contracts on Corda?

I know about their website: https://explore.corda.zone/
But this link have very few usecases and those also with no documentation and some with no code/git links.

Is there any other repo/website where I can find the solutions developed on corda?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://explore.corda.zone is still very much a work in progress and new projects (with code) will be added to the library over the coming months.

In the meantime, you can check out https://www.corda.net/samples/ for sample CorDapps. The following repos also have additional sample CorDapps

- https://github.com/roger3cev
- https://github.com/CaisR3
- https://github.com/JoelDudleyR3